# Why does re.sub("[^0-9]", "", n) add a number to my list on some computers?

Tags: python, sorting, python-re

I'm building a sorting script in python and the files are sorted by there id(number) and I use the `re.sub("[^0-9]", "", n)` function to get all the numbers and append them to a list. But on some computers it adds a `2` to the list. For example the real name of the file is `1654829844` and the output is `21654829844` but this is only one some computers. Maybe there is a simple solution because im very unfamiliar the the `re` module?

This is my code to get all the numbers:

```
#appends all numbers of the files
#appends all numbers of the files
#the number list is the original list
#the test list is the list where i remove the first number to make the name correct
def number_read(pdfs):
    number = []
    try:
        for n in pdfs:
            number.append(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", n))

        #number = [sub[1 : ] for sub in number]
        
        for i in number:
            if i not in numbers : 
                numbers.append(i)
    except:
        raise num_sort_error("A number sorting error has occourd")
    return number
```

This is my output:

Wrong:

```
['21654826187', '21654826529', '21654826747', '21654827126', '21654827302', '21654827311', '21654827999', '21654828292', '21654828508', '21654828713', '21654828789', '21654829770', '21654829844', '21654830153', '21654830362', '21654833294', '21654834237', '21654904402', '21654906426', '21654907268', '21654908243', '21654908274', '21654908947', '21654908994', '21654909453', '21654909719', '21654937218']
```

Correct output:

```
['1654826187', '1654826529', '1654826747', '1654827126', '1654827302', '1654827311', '1654827999', '1654828292', '1654828508', '1654828713', '1654828789', '1654829770', '1654829844', '1654830153', '1654830362', '1654833294', '1654834237', '1654904402', '1654906426', '1654907268', '1654908243', '1654908274', '1654908947', '1654908994', '1654909453', '1654909719', '1654937218']
```

Comment: It is suspicious that you are appending to a `numbers` list that is *global*. This means the result of a previous call will leak into the results of a next call. Avoid that your function mutates a global variable.

Comment: Secondly, you have an unconditional `return` statement in a `for` loop, which means that loop will only iterate once.  I don't understand the role of `test` and `tests`, but because of this `return` statement you will get different results in `numbers` and `tests`.

Comment: Agree with the above. Also, you mention that you made the `test` list to try to fix the issue with the first digit. Can you post your code before you tried that? If you just use `number`, what is the expected output and what is the actual output? Try to reduce your code to the smallest piece that exhibits the issue.

Comment: it was a test function to easily switch and compare from and te test if i remove the first number to make the names correct but thats lazy codeing i would like to know how i can avoid this problem because from my exprience it didn't add the number but on a other pc i did

Comment: i added my output and made my code bare bones

Comment: Are you sure to have the same _pdfs_ input on the computers with the bug?

Comment: A _collection_ of unsorted unique values is a _set_, which is in python `myset = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}` . No need to loop over the first list to build the second one, just use a `unique_numbers = {}`.

Comment: Yes i know for sure i have the same pdfs and the seconde part of my code is for making the vaules unique the because the first list is just the colection of all the pdf file ids with more than one with the same id

Comment: Does `pdfs` contain a list of the full file path or just the names of the files in the directories? If the former, then you could get an extra `2` if there is a `2` somewhere else in the path, for example `/home/user2/foo/bar/baz1654826187.pdf` or `C:\Users\User2\foo\bar\baz1654826187.pdf`.

Comment: it contains the full path, and you were absolutely right it was the path tnx you guy for all your help

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved.